# Groupby dates quaterly in a pandas dataframe and find count for their occurence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

My Dataframe looks like

```
"dataframe_time" 
   INSERTED_UTC
0    2018-05-29
1    2018-05-22
2    2018-02-10
3    2018-04-30
4    2018-03-02
5    2018-11-26
6    2018-03-07
7    2018-05-12
8    2019-02-03
9    2018-08-03
10   2018-04-27
```

```
print(type(dataframe_time['INSERTED_UTC'].iloc[1]))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

I am trying to group the dates together and find the count of their occurrence quaterly. Desired Output -

```
Quarter         Count
2018-03-31        3   
2018-06-30        5   
2018-09-30        1   
2018-12-31        1   
2019-03-31        1
2019-06-30        0
```

I am running the following command to group them together

```
dataframe_time['INSERTED_UTC'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Q'))

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First are `date`s converted to datetimes and then is used  [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `on` for get column with datetimes:

```
dataframe_time.INSERTED_UTC = pd.to_datetime(dataframe_time.INSERTED_UTC)
df = dataframe_time.resample('Q', on='INSERTED_UTC').size().reset_index(name='Count')
```

Or your solution is possible change to:

```
df = (dataframe_time.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Q', key='INSERTED_UTC'))
                    .size()
                    .reset_index(name='Count'))
print (df)
  INSERTED_UTC  Count
0   2018-03-31      3
1   2018-06-30      5
2   2018-09-30      1
3   2018-12-31      1
4   2019-03-31      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the dates to quarters by `to_period('Q')` and group by those:

```
df.INSERTED_UTC = pd.to_datetime(df.INSERTED_UTC)
df.groupby(df.INSERTED_UTC.dt.to_period('Q')).size()
```

You can also use `value_counts`:

```
df.INSERTED_UTC.dt.to_period('Q').value_counts()
```

Output:

```
INSERTED_UTC
2018Q1    3
2018Q2    5
2018Q3    1
2018Q4    1
2019Q1    1
Freq: Q-DEC, dtype: int64
```